# Vue reactivity bug

Tags: c#, vuejs3, .net-5

Let me preface this by saying frontend is not my forte..

I have a dropdown component and all I want is when I hit the reset button is for it to revert to the placeholder text instead of keeping the selected option.
I have zero idea why this isn't working. I've read the docs for two days and tried many things to no avail. To me it's clearly reactive because it's reactive in other parts, but when I set it to null, no reactivity fires.

Dropdown.vue (largely from [here](https://github.com/mikerodham/vue-dropdowns) with some small edits)

```
<template>
    <div class="btn-group">

        <li @click="toggleMenu()" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-placeholder" v-if="isPlaceholder()">
            {{placeholderText}}
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </li>
        <li @click="toggleMenu()" class="dropdown-toggle" v-else>
            {{ selectedOption }}
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </li>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" v-if="showMenu">
            <li v-for="(option, idx) in options" :key="idx">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="updateOption(option)" draggable="false">
                    {{ option }}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            options: {
                type: Array
            },
            selected: {
                type: String
            },
            placeholder: {
                type: String
            },
            closeOnOutsideClick: {
              type: Boolean,
              default: true,
            },
        },

        data() {
            return {
                selectedOption: '',
                showMenu: false,
                placeholderText: 'Please select an item',
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.selectedOption = this.selected;
            if (this.placeholder)
            {
                this.placeholderText = this.placeholder;
            }

            if (this.closeOnOutsideClick) {
              document.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
            }
        },

        beforeUnmount() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.clickHandler);
        },

        methods: {
            updateOption(option) {
                this.selectedOption = option;
                this.showMenu = false;
                this.$emit('update-option', this.selectedOption);
            },

            clearOption() {
                this.selectedOption = null;
                this.showMenu = false;
                console.log("reset:", this.selectedOption);
            },

            toggleMenu() {
                this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
            },

            clickHandler(event) {
                const { target } = event;
                const { $el } = this;

                if (!$el.contains(target)) {
                  this.showMenu = false;
                }
            },

            isPlaceholder() {
                return (this.selectedOption === undefined || this.selectedOption === null || this.selectedOption === '');
            }
        },


    }
</script>

<style>

    .btn-group {
        min-width: 160px;
        height: 40px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

        .btn-group a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    .dropdown-toggle {
        color: #636b6f;
        min-width: 160px;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
        text-transform: none;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        border: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(#009688, #009688), linear-gradient(#D2D2D2, #D2D2D2);
        background-size: 0 2px, 100% 1px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center bottom, center calc(100% - 1px);
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: background 0s ease-out;
        float: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        user-select: none;
    }

        .dropdown-toggle:hover {
            background: #e1e1e1;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    .dropdown-menu {
        display: inherit !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        float: left;
        min-width: 160px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 2px 0 0;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
        background-clip: padding-box;
    }

        .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            padding: 10px 30px;
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.6;
            color: #333333;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-decoration: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

            .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
                background: #efefef;
                color: #409FCB;
            }

        .dropdown-menu > li {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
        }

    .caret {
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        height: 0;
        margin-left: -24px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-top: 4px dashed;
        border-top: 4px solid \9;
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        right: 10px;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
    }

        li.dropdown-toggle::after {
            display: none;
        }
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <form @reset.prevent="onReset">
        <dropdown v-if="foo.bar" class="my-dropdown"
                  :options="myOptions"
                  :selected="foo.bar.name"
                  @update-option="onSelected"
                  :placeholder="'Select a MyOption'">
        </dropdown>

        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    import dropdown from './components/Dropdown.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            dropdown,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                foo: {},
                myOptions: [],
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onReset() {
                console.log("Resetting...");
                this.foo = {};
                this.foo['bar'] = {};
                this.foo['bar']['name'] = '';

                dropdown.methods.clearOption();
            },
            onSelected(selected) {
                this.foo.bar.name = selected;
                console.log(selected);
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.onReset();
        },
        mounted() {
            this.myOptions = ['A', 'B'];
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    #app {
        font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        text-align: center;
        color: #2c3e50;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }

    .my-dropdown {
        border-radius: 5px;

        ::v-deep(.dropdown-toggle)
        {
            color: tomato;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: 800;
        }

        ::v-deep(.dropdown-toggle-placeholder) {
            color: #c4c4c4;
        }

    }
</style>
```

When I hit the reset button and call `dropdown.methods.clearOption()` Dropdown sets `this.selectedOption` to `null` (I've also tried empty string, etc). All my console.logs look fine and make it appear it worked, but the  `v-if="isPlaceholder()"` and `v-else` just are not working. The selected option remains in the dropbox instead of it reverting back to the placeholder text.

What am I doing wrong????

Comment: If you console.log the value in `isPlaceholder` after the reset what is it?

Comment: `selected: B`
`placeholder: B`
`Resetting...`
`reset: null`
`placeholder: B`

Comment: Wouldn't the `$emit` just trigger an update to the outside to handle? So the App.vue would execute its `onSelected` to be null. If I put `this.$emit('update-option', null);` inside `clearOption` I get `this.$emit is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Assuming a bug in Vue's reactivity based on your own code without even testing it... it's pretty bold of you.</strike> I didn't dive deeper as I noticed really nasty bug in your own code. You're calling `dropdown.methods.clearOption();` function directly in the App's instance. As for me, Vue interprets it perfectly fine but JS doesn't work the way you may think it works. First of, using a method like that you've lost the [*this* context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) along the way.

To fix this problem in Vue, you need to grab a reference to the component you're trying to call upon. To create references in Vue, you need to add a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) attribute to the App component's template:

```html
<dropdown
  ref="myDropDown"
  v-if="foo.bar"
  class="my-dropdown"
  :options="myOptions"
  :selected="foo.bar.name"
  @update-option="onSelected"
  :placeholder="'Select a MyOption'">
</dropdown>
```

Then you can reach the component instance through `myDropDown` reference, for example:

```js
onReset() {
  // the `?.` is an optional chaining operator
  // can be easily replaced with an if statement
  this.$refs.myDropDown?.clearOption();
}
```

Also as I noticed, you're using `v-if` statement in your template, it may end up in missing `$refs.myDropDown` reference at this point. To solve this, you could defer calling the method by [Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

```js
// defers clearing the dropdown options
Vue.nextTick(() => this.$refs.myDropDown?.clearOption())
```

Anyway, writing components like this - is an opposite of what reactivity in Vue have to offer though. You can always watch on props changes and make the component behave accordingly, without need to grab any references.

Comment: I meant more so a bug in my code relating to reactivity than within Vue. I figured I was somehow operating on a different `this` but couldn't figure out where. I even tried the `$refs` before but didn't add `ref` attribute to the dropdown. When I do the reset works. I don't want to do any anti-patterns, it's difficult to pick up these things coming from a c++ backend background. Could you provide some documentation or examples for how I could use watches to handle this instead of the anti-pattern?

Comment: Also I've noticed that you're using `v-if` statement, at this point, `this.$refs.myDropDown` may be unreachable. Try a trick with [this.$nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) function.

Comment: I think models should be a good start about handling such situations, to wach props, you can use [watch](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) methods.